# Save point in enter the gungeon

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I managed to defeat Gatling gull and the twin bullets on chamber one. Chamber two is a little more difficult; I get creamed after visiting 3-5 rooms. When I die it sends me back to chamber 1 with the same character or a new one.

Does this game have a save of sorts which would let you start from chamber 2 or do I just have to tough it out? I'd assumed those other doors on character select screen do that, but they remain shut :(

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no.  Like Binding of Isaac, you need to start over at the beginning every time.  Then again, do you REALLY want to enter the lower levels with only your starting guns?

Comment: Having said that, there is a guy that you can find that asks you for items like the guy in Spelunky who builds shortcuts...

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll need a perfect boss fight. It's hard enough trying not to die against them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get a perfect boss fight, then Sherpa will appear the next floor you go to. Talk to him and he'll let you know he'll fix the elevator. You'll find him in the elevator shaft. He'll then let you know what he needs to fix the elevators. If you get all the requirements, he'll unlock items as well.

Tips:

- 1 perfect boss fight, then meet Sherpa, then perfect boss fight of the floor you want to skip and talk to Sherpa again. (in the elevator shaft, not the Breach)

http://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Shortcuts

Comment: Turns out Sherpa appears even if you don't perfect a boss fight.  Not sure what the criteria is, probably clearing the first chamber a bunch of times.

Comment: I think he appears the first time you clear the first boss after unlocking the acquisitions shop

Answer (score 3):

Although there is no 'quicksave' feature in Enter the Gungeon, shortcuts do exist. To unlock them, you first need to defeat any of the first chamber bosses without making any mistakes (you will know when this happens, because a Master Round will spawn as a reward).

After doing so, the second chambers elevator area will have the Tailor (carpet guy) sitting next to the entrance. He will explain to you that he wants to 'repair the elevators'. From this point on, the Tailor will appear in the elevator shaft and a symbol will appear on the entrance to the shaft to note that he is inside.

To enter the shaft, exit the elevator and wait for it to drop down and then enter the hole. Inside you can meet the tailor. He will ask for various items to make the shortcut. After giving him the required items (see below), the elevator room in the Breach will be unlocked and the Tailor will move down a chamber. For each unlocked shortcut you will also receive an achievement.

Additionally, from the third chamber onwards, the Resourceful Rat will appear and give you the option to choose between three guns. You can take one gun on the third floor, two guns on the fourth floor and all guns on the fifth floor.

Furthermore, unlocking the shortcut to the second chamber will place the Busted TV in the elevator room (required for unlocking the Robot) and unlocking the shortcut to the fifth chamber will unlock Boss Rush (accessible by entering the skull elevator in the Breach. This costs 7 Hegemony Credits after the first time).

Lastly, Hegemony Credits are not dropped on Elevator Runs.

## Required items

Second chamber:

- 3 Blanks.
- 3 Keys and 120 money.
- 10 Hegemony Credits.
- The master round from the first chamber.

Reward: Gunboots.

Third chamber:

- 3 Armor (or 6 if you are playing the Robot).
- 4 Keys and 180 money.
- 15 Hegemony Credits.
- The master round from the second chamber.

Reward: R2-G2

Fourth chamber:

- 4 Junk (obtained from shooting closed chests).
- 5 Keys and 240 money.
- 20 Hegemony Credits.
- The master round from the third chamber.

Reward: Gungine

Fifth chamber

- 6 heart containers (only need to be shown, heart containers are kept).
- 6 Keys and 300 money.
- 25 Hegemony Credits.
- The master round from the fourth chamber.

Rewards: AKey-47 and Boss Rush.